# Selecting rows when there is a change in the value of column from the previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:-

```
Name   Status  Timestamp
Ben      1     2015-01-01
Ben      1     2015-01-02
Joe      1     2015-11-12   
Joe      2     2015-11-13
Joe      2     2016-12-14
Joe      2     2016-12-15
Paul     1     2015-08-16
Paul     1     2015-08-17
Paul     3     2015-08-18
Paul     3     2015-08-19
Mark     2     2015-09-20
Mark     2     2015-09-25
Mark     2     2015-09-26
Mark     3     2015-10-27
```

I need a query that returns only the rows where there is a change in the 'Status'.  It should return the row when the 'Status' is changed and also the previous row.
For instance the result should be like the below:-

```
Name   Status  Timestamp
Joe      1     2015-11-12   
Joe      2     2015-11-13
Paul     1     2015-08-17
Paul     3     2015-08-18
Mark     2     2015-09-26
Mark     3     2015-10-27
```

How can I achieve this result.

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: SQL Sever 2014 Standard Edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` with a `CASE` and `LAG` and `LEAD` to calculate what rows to select. this will work for versions 2012 and higher:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE
(
    Name varchar(4),
    [Status] int,
    [Timestamp] date
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Joe', 1, '2015-11-12'),   
('Joe', 2, '2015-11-13'),
('Joe', 2, '2016-12-14'),
('Joe', 2, '2016-12-15'),
('Paul' ,1, '2015-08-16'),
('Paul' ,1, '2015-08-17'),
('Paul' ,3, '2015-08-18'),
('Paul' ,3, '2015-08-19'),
('Mark' ,2, '2015-09-20'),
('Mark' ,2, '2015-09-25'),
('Mark' ,2, '2015-09-26'),
('Mark' ,3, '2015-10-27')
```

The cte - Note that I use both lag and lead inside the case expression.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Name,
            [Status],
            [Timestamp],
            CASE WHEN LAG([Status]) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Timestamp]) <> [Status] OR
                      LEAD([Status]) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Timestamp]) <> [Status] THEN 
                1
            END As Filter
    FROM @T
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT  Name,
        [Status],
        [Timestamp]
FROM CTE
WHERE Filter = 1
```

Results:

```
Name    Status  Timestamp
Joe     1       12.11.2015 00:00:00
Joe     2       13.11.2015 00:00:00
Mark    2       26.09.2015 00:00:00
Mark    3       27.10.2015 00:00:00
Paul    1       17.08.2015 00:00:00
Paul    3       18.08.2015 00:00:00
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/NVT91177)

Comment: I think it is not true - `Paul     1     2015-08-16` will be selected.

Comment: Yes I also think so becuase Paul 1 2015-08-16 is the first row in that a partition.

Comment: Think you might need an `ORDER BY [Timestamp]` at the end of that query

Comment: That would put Joe last... also, I'm pretty sure the OP can add the order by clause if needed...

Comment: SQL server seems ordering the result by the window function instead of natural order.

Comment: @Eric SQL Server choose it's own order unless an order by clause exists. that order might be different from one execution to the other. No relational database guarantees the order of the result set unless order by is specified, since tables are unsorted by nature.

Answer (score 0):

This can be user on versions starting with 2005:

```
declare @t table (Name varchar(100),   S int, T date);
insert into @t values
('Joe',     1     ,'2015-11-12'),   
('Joe',     2     ,'2015-11-13'),
('Joe',     2     ,'2016-12-14'),
('Joe',     2     ,'2016-12-15'),
('Paul',    1     ,'2015-08-16'),
('Paul',    1     ,'2015-08-17'),
('Paul',    3     ,'2015-08-18'),
('Paul',    3     ,'2015-08-19'),
('Mark',     2     ,'2015-09-20'),
('Mark',     2     ,'2015-09-25'),
('Mark',     2     ,'2015-09-26'),
('Mark',     3     ,'2015-10-27');

with cte as 
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Name order by T) as rn
from @t
)

,cte1 as
(
select c1.Name, c1.S as S1, c1.T as T1, c2.S as S2, c2.T as T2
from cte c1 join cte c2
       on c1.rn + 1 = c2.rn
          and c1.Name = c2.Name
where c1.S <> c2.S
)

select Name,
       case n 
              when 1 then S1
              when 2 then S2
       end as Status,
       case n 
              when 1 then T1
              when 2 then T2
       end as Timestamp
from cte1 cross join (select 1 n union all select 2) nums;
```

And this is the same but for versions starting with 2012:

```
declare @t table (Name varchar(100),   S int, T date);
insert into @t values
('Joe',     1     ,'2015-11-12'),   
('Joe',     2     ,'2015-11-13'),
('Joe',     2     ,'2016-12-14'),
('Joe',     2     ,'2016-12-15'),
('Paul',    1     ,'2015-08-16'),
('Paul',    1     ,'2015-08-17'),
('Paul',    3     ,'2015-08-18'),
('Paul',    3     ,'2015-08-19'),
('Mark',     2     ,'2015-09-20'),
('Mark',     2     ,'2015-09-25'),
('Mark',     2     ,'2015-09-26'),
('Mark',     3     ,'2015-10-27');

with cte as 
(
select name,
       S as S1, 
       lead(S) over(partition by Name order by T) S2,
       T as T1, 
       lead(T) over(partition by Name order by T) T2
from @t
)

,cte1 as
(
select *
from cte
where S1 <> S2
)

select Name,
       case n 
              when 1 then S1
              when 2 then S2
       end as Status,
       case n 
              when 1 then T1
              when 2 then T2
       end as Timestamp

from cte1 cross join (select 1 n union all select 2) nums;
```

Comment: You really should work on your naming skills. Your query made me dizzy.

Comment: The answer reports the original names. Maybe it's the author that should work on these skills when gives the field names that are **reserved words**? I just did not want to use square brackets everywhere

Comment: I agree that reserved words should not be used for column names, but that's also true for single letters (I also don't like abbreviations for that matter, if I had a column for advertisements I would never name it adds). Names should be meaningful. That's the bottom line.

Comment: I never use them in my production code. For users that are "busy" enough to prepare the input data as CREATE/INSERT scripts, usage of such abbreviations may help to start to think about their naming conventions